# Inconsistent auto-linking in transcript

Tags: bug, chat, hyperlinks, onebox

I was looking through a chat transcript when I came upon a link that was not auto-hyperlinked. I did some more digging in the [Sandbox](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1/sandbox) and it appears that only in message one boxes, links are not auto-hyperlinked.

---

This works:

```
[goatsarebetterthansheep.com](http://goatsarebetterthansheep.com/)
```

but this doesn't:

```
http://goatsarebetterthansheep.com
```

---

Here's an image describing it:

[image]

[[source]](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1/conversation/borked-message-oneboxing-with-link)

Describing the image, markdown in message oneboxes work along with links to images, and links using `[foo](bar)` syntax, this seems to only affect plain urls getting auto-hyperlinked.